# NextJS environment variables undefined?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I've made a script to save some static data to my filesystem which looks like this

./lib/createLinks.js

```js
const contentful = require('contentful')
const fs = require('fs')

require('dotenv').config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})

async function createLinks() {
  const client = contentful.createClient({
    space: process.env.NEXT_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
    accessToken: process.env.NEXT_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  })

  const data = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: 'news',
  })

  fs.writeFile('./data/links.json', JSON.stringify(data), (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.info('Global data written to file')
  })
}

async function main() {
  try {
    await createLinks()
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err)
  }
}

main()
```

```js
"create-links": "node ./lib/createLinks",
    "dev": "yarn create-links && next dev",
    "build": "yarn create-links && next build",
```

However I can't access my environment variables which is undefined when I try to run this.

My variables are placed in the root in .env.local

Why is this happening?

Comment: Is your `NODE_ENV` set to `local`? If not `dotenv` won't be able to load what's in your `.env.local` file.

Comment: I don't know, how do I check this?

Comment: You can console log the `process.env.NODE_ENV` variable in `createLinks.js` file. If you're not setting it explicitly, then it won't have a value (unless something else sets its value).

Comment: Tried this, and it is also undefined. Hmm.

Comment: I solved it by adding "dev": "NODE_ENV=local yarn create-links && next dev". However I'm not sure this will work if I try to build it on netlify?

Comment: If you got a solution please answer your own question, this way it can help others.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding the following to my package.json

```js
"dev": "NODE_ENV=local yarn create-links && next dev",
"build": "NODE_ENV=local yarn create-links && next build",
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this + node_env=local helped my situation

```js
process.env['NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL']
```